# Is there a javascript/jquery function to Submit a Razor Form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, kendo-ui

I have a Razor form and I would prefer to not have to use a button to submit the information.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitYearDept", "Request", FormMethod.Post, new { 
id = "SubmitYearDeptForm" }))
{
    <div class="aidYearDiv" style="float: left; margin-right: 1em">
        @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.AidYear)
              .Name("AidYear")
              .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "aidYearList" })
              .DataTextField("Name")
              .DataValueField("Name")
              .OptionLabel("Select a Year")
              .DataSource(source =>
              {
                  source.Read(read =>
                  {
                      read.Action("Filtering_AidYear", "Request");
                  });
              })
              .Events(e =>
              {
              e.Change("onAppChange");
              }))
    </div>
    <div class="departmentDiv">
        @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.DeptCode)
                  .Name("DeptCode")
                  .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "departmentList" })
                  .DataTextField("DeptName")
                  .DataValueField("DeptCode")
                  .OptionLabel("Select a Department")
                  .DataSource(source =>
                  {
                      source.Read(read =>
                      {
                          read.Action("Filtering_Dept", "Request");
                      });
                  })
                  .Events(e =>
                  {
                      e.DataBound("onDataBound");
                      e.Change("onAppChange");
                  }))

        <input type="submit" id="SubmitNomineeBtn" name="SubmitNomineeBtn" class="submitButton" value="Submit" />
    </div>
}
```

I would like that if both drop downs have a value then submit the form.  The reason I would prefer to not use a drop down is because I want information to change based on the values of the drop downs and allow the user to not have to hit a submit button every time they change the value of one of the drop downs.

Comment: First, an MVC "Razor Form" is just a wrapper around `<form>` - so it's no different.  2nd you're using a Kendo drop down, so you need to find the `change` event for that and wire it up to `form.submit()` eg `function onAppChange() { $(this).closest("form").submit(); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is if my condition is true I'm just going to simulate a button click for the user.  And so the user doesn't see the button I just made changed the style of the button to be display: none